# Manipulate rows based on condition

Tags: pandas

I want to manipulate pandas rows based on conditions. An example is that I want to overwrite each field in `method` with the string 'BBBB' if the field in `type` is a numpy NaN:

```
newcolumn = []
for index, row in results_DF.iterrows():
    newcolumn.append('BBBB' if row['type'] is np.nan else row['method'])
results_DF['method'] = pd.Series(newcolumn)
```

This implementation looks pretty ugly. How to write it nicer - in more a functional style?

Comment: mask=results_DF['type'].isnull()
results_DF.loc[mask]='BBBB'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with boolean amsk created by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
results_DF.loc[results_DF['type'].isna(), 'method'] = 'BBBB'

#oldier pandas versions
#results_DF.loc[results_DF['type'].isnull(), 'method'] = 'BBBB'
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
results_DF['method'] = np.where(results_DF['type'].isna(), 'BBBB', results_DF['method'])
```

Or solution by @Jon Clements, thank you:

```
results_DF['method'] = results_DF.where(results_DF['type'].notnull(), 'BBBB')
```

**Sample**:

```
results_DF = pd.DataFrame({'method': ['a','s','d'],
                           'type':[np.nan, np.nan, 4]})

print (results_DF)
  method  type
0      a   NaN
1      s   NaN
2      d   4.0

results_DF.loc[results_DF['type'].isna(), 'method'] = 'BBBB'
print (results_DF)
  method  type
0   BBBB   NaN
1   BBBB   NaN
2      d   4.0
```

Comment: Or: `results_DF['method'].where(results_DF['type'].notnull(), 'BBBB', inplace=True)` ?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
mask=results_DF['type'].isnull()
results_DF.loc[mask]='BBBB'
```

Comment: But it is not null, is it?

Comment: yeah it's null. For more details visit https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html